# Count unique column values given another column in PySpark

Tags: python, pyspark, group-by, count

I am trying to count `Date` for each unique `ID` in Pyspark.

```
+-------------------+----------+
|               Date|        ID|
+-------------------+----------+
|2022-03-19 00:00:00|   Ax3838J|
|2022-03-11 00:00:00|   Ax3838J|
|2021-11-01 00:00:00|   Ax3838J|
|2021-10-27 00:00:00|   Ax3838J|
|2021-10-25 00:00:00|   Bz3838J|
|2021-10-22 00:00:00|   Bz3838J|
|2021-10-18 00:00:00|   Bz3838J|
|2021-10-15 00:00:00|   Rr7422u|
|2021-09-22 00:00:00|   Rr742uL|
+-------------------+----------+
```

When I tried

```
df.groupBy('ID').count('Date').show()
```

I got the error:
 `_api() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given`
which makes sense, but I am not sure what are the other techniques exits to count so in PySpark.

How do I count unique `Date` values with this:

```
df.groupBy('ID').count().show()
```

Expected output:

```
+-------------------+----------+
|               Date|        ID|
+-------------------+----------+
|                  4|   Ax3838J|
|                  3|   Bz3838J|
|                  2|   Rr742uL|
+-------------------+----------+
```

Comment: please add the desire output for same

Comment: Try this then --> df.groupby("ID").agg(countDistinct("Date").alias("count")).show()

Comment: if you need I can add a working version of code with output

Comment: Yes please, already updated the expected out

Comment: why is this not included in your output "Rr742uL"?

Comment: that was a typo, fixed it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please find the working version of expected output. I am running code on spark-3.

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import countDistinct

data = [["2022-03-19 00:00:00", "Ax3838J"], ["2022-03-11 00:00:00", "Ax3838J"], ["2021-11-01 00:00:00", "Ax3838J"], ["2021-10-27 00:00:00", "Ax3838J"], ["2021-10-25 00:00:00", "Bz3838J"], ["2021-10-22 00:00:00", "Bz3838J"], ["2021-10-18 00:00:00", "Bz3838J"], ["2021-10-15 00:00:00", "Rr7422u"], ["2021-09-22 00:00:00", "Rr742uL"]]
df = spark.createDataFrame(data, ['Date', 'ID'])
df.show()
+-------------------+-------+
|               Date|     ID|
+-------------------+-------+
|2022-03-19 00:00:00|Ax3838J|
|2022-03-11 00:00:00|Ax3838J|
|2021-11-01 00:00:00|Ax3838J|
|2021-10-27 00:00:00|Ax3838J|
|2021-10-25 00:00:00|Bz3838J|
|2021-10-22 00:00:00|Bz3838J|
|2021-10-18 00:00:00|Bz3838J|
|2021-10-15 00:00:00|Rr742uL|
|2021-09-22 00:00:00|Rr742uL|
+-------------------+-------+

df.groupby("ID").agg(countDistinct("Date").alias("count")).show()
+-------+-----+
|     ID|count|
+-------+-----+
|Rr742uL|    2|
|Ax3838J|    4|
|Bz3838J|    3|
+-------+-----+
```

Please let me know if you need any help and if its solve your purpose please accept it

Comment: Try it now it will resolved the issue

Comment: perfect, thanks. Btw, if you want more, here is one unresolved one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71658675/merge-two-dataframes-with-conditions-in-pyspark/71659117#71659117

Comment: I believe this link point it to here only. and you can also upvote it as you have already accepted the answer

Comment: Updated the link. For reference, this was the initial problem which is a subproblem of the above added link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71647549/resampling-datetime-by-date-in-pyspark/71649076?noredirect=1#comment126629011_71649076

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
df.groupBy('ID').count(distinct 'Date').show()
```

Comment: getting `SyntaxError: invalid syntax` right before `Date`. Are we missing anything?

Comment: you can use countDistinct() function instead of count(), also can you show me the error

Comment: please check the above comments if you wish to solve more. Links attached.